# How to choose suitable LED power supply

Tags: led, led-driver, constant-current

Can I replace an LED power supply with this output: DC 50~57 V, 280~300 mA

with a new supply with this output: DC 45~85 V, 300 mA ±5% ?

In other words, does it matter that the output voltage has a greater range on the proposed replacement?

Both are rated at 18-24 W.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that replacement is suitable.

For an LED driver, which is a constant current power supply, what is required is that the voltage range (called compliance voltage) match or exceed the range on the old device and that the current be similar or less. Both of those are true so the replacement is equivalent.

Comment: Thank you - I believe that answers my question

Comment: Ah, apologies to macean and you, I misread the question, which I found ambiguous but you clearly didn't :-) Thought it was specing old PSU and new PSU, not PSU and driver. Have rephrased @macean question and deleted my comment there. (I hadn't explained my dv here, the question comment covered it.) Please edit your question any old how so I can change my downvote to an upvote and I'll also delete this comment.

Comment: To be honest I'm thoroughly confused with the rephrased question - I thought my original question was quite clear as it seems did the answerer. No matter I've ordered the replacement now so I'm happy.

Comment: @TonyM I can't make sense of your edits. Maybe you should revert them?

Comment: Then I'm honestly more confused by your confusion. But the original was hard to follow so I can't put it back. Best way is if you edit the question to a new and clear form of what you knew you were answering. It must be very simple at its core, quick to knock off. Thanks.

Comment: OK I've changed it. Maybe I confused things by not knowing the difference between a PSU and a driver. Anyway I hope it's clear now:-)

Comment: An LED driver is a semi-technical term for a constant current power supply, so either would be correct. You're asking for a replacement power supply, and from the spec we can tell that it is a constant current LED driver.

Comment: Understood. For the record in the original question I used both terms in different places, having noticed the description on the label half way through asking the question. So @TonyM's confusion is understandable.